# How to send current location of user from flutter app to firebase database in background?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_background_service , geolocator and  cloud_firestore packages to get users location even if the app if in background or foreground and send the lat,long to firebase database. but it's only working
when I don't initialize firebase, a notification shows up with current lat,long but once I  initialize firebase it don't push current lat,long to database and throws this  error (**[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp**

but I have initialized it.

I want to send current users latitude and longitude to database even if the app is in background or fore gourd.  And this is my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initializ();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: First(),
  ));
}



Future initializ() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(),
      androidConfiguration:
          AndroidConfiguration(isForegroundMode: true, onStart: OnStart));
  await service.startService();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void OnStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        String long = position.longitude.toString();
        String lat = position.latitude.toString();
        print(lat);
        var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        var users = db.collection("rashi");
        await users.add({"lat": long.toString(), "lng": lat.toString()});
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
            title: "Asif", content: "longitude : $long , latitude : $lat ");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call method like this

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await initializ();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: First(),
  )
);
}
```

first initialize firebaseapp and then call other method

Comment: still same issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).